Acitivity is recreated after navigating to forceground
I am creating an Android application, that bounds to a Service.
bindService(intent,
        this,
        ComponentActivity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE or
                ComponentActivity.BIND_IMPORTANT or
                ComponentActivity.BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND or
                ComponentActivity.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY
        )

When I tap the Home button to put my app into the background the Activity's onStop method is called.
When I tap on the AppIcon to take the application back to the foreground, the Activity's onCreate method is called, this means my activity is created after navigating from the background.
This is my configuration for the activity
        <activity
        android:name="com.company.example.activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation|uiMode|mcc|mnc"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data android:name="distractionOptimized" android:value="true"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER_APP"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

I want to avoid activity being re-created after navigating from the background.

Why do you have <category> tags for HOME, DEFAULT and LAUNCHER_APP? You don't need those and they may be causing you problems.
